# Browser notifications for omni channel chats in Lightning Experience

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console, omnichannel, notification

Is this possible using settings available in the UI or does this require a custom component to be created?

I imagine many have this issue, whereby unless the service agent spends all their time in the omni channel widget in the bottom corner of the screen, they end up missing live chat requests as there's no better way to get the agent's attention.

Comment: Have you checked https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=live_agent_chat_notifications_supported_browsers.htm&type=5 according to which, the types of chat notifications that are supported are determined by the web browsers your agents use.

Comment: I did but according to the documentation, these are only available for Salesforce Classic and our team is using Lightning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a package from Salesforce Labs AppExchange package called [Conversations Notifications](https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t3k000001mQ7b) . This allows customizable notifications for Chat & Messaging customers using the Lightning Service Console.

This Conversations Notifications package offers the ability for:

1. Browser Notifications for a new Chat or Messaging Session routed via Omni-Channel.
2. Browser Notifications for a new inbound Chat message.
3. Customizable sound for a new inbound Chat message.

See a demo video for this functionality [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AtmF0gnRctWcOvzw-VSA4yzFIXorlV0o/view?usp=sharing).  Installation manual [here](https://org62.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/000000000062/a/0M000000JJwR/uYFU5vXtwaP3QX4AVxwd0.ZKaO84wajzQErda4dHuiY)

Note: As this is a [Salesforce Labs package](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332395&type=1&mode=1), it not officially supported.
This is available in Lightning only.

I have tested this functionality in my org and see a desktop notification. See inline image
[image]

Comment: @Antonio Have you been able to check this functionality on your org? Happy to answer any follow-up queries. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Swetha I'm interested in this package but I struggle to find it on AppExchange. Installed it in a sandbox, but couldn't get it to work, so interested to find out a bit more info. Thank you

Comment: HI @alesremta Can you tell me which aspect is not working so I can suggest better?

Comment: Hey @Swetha. thanks for getting back. Not getting any notifications, not even like requests to allow them.
Is this package listed on AppExchange or your private one?